# Certificate was deleted from Smart Card / Token while signing XML. How's that possible?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, rsa-sha256

I had a few `XML` docs, each has around 50 to 100 individual blocks/ tags, that needed to be individually singed using SHA256 and send to a web service, so I've made a loop thru the docs and thru it nodes, got it all signed up using `c#` code below.

Everything went well as I was testing it with a smart card, even got the "`OK`" response from server during 3 or 4 times until suddenly my private key went null, then I got the forbidden anonymous login message from `WS`, little did I know I took a different certificate, this time an USB Token one, and same thing happened, fine for 3, 4 times and then gone again! I really don't know what's going on or what went wrong! Does anyone have clue? Thanks.

**PS:** Before it stopped  working the `signer.ComputeSignature();` method was asking for password, now the exception its on:

```
var key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)pCertificado.PrivateKey;

key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;       

public string SignSHA256(string pDocument, string id, X509Certificate2 pCertificado)
{            
    string signatureCn14Transform = @"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315";
    string signatureMethod = @"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
    string digestMethod = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
    string signatureReferenceURI = "#" + id;


    CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), signatureMethod);            

    XmlDocument xmlDocToSign = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocToSign.LoadXml(pDocument);

    SignedXml signer = new SignedXml(xmlDocToSign);            

    var key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)pCertificado.PrivateKey;
    key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    signer.SigningKey = key; 
    signer.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = signatureMethod;

    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

    XmlDsigExcC14NTransform cn14Transform = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
    cn14Transform.Algorithm = signatureCn14Transform;
    reference.AddTransform(cn14Transform);
    reference.Uri = signatureReferenceURI;
    reference.DigestMethod = digestMethod;
    signer.AddReference(reference);

    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();          
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(pCertificado));
    signer.KeyInfo = keyInfo;            
    signer.ComputeSignature();

    xmlDocToSign.DocumentElement.AppendChild(signer.GetXml());

    return xmlDocToSign.OuterXml;
}
```

Comment: I have also checked the Cert manager safeNet (token), and safeSign standart (smart card) and there is no private key or certificate on both.

Comment: Don't know what else to do, RCA  function was correct by server so i though that caused the problem, I've changed to http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 and add  signature enveloped http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature like they told me to, same thing happen. Pls any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`key.PersistKeyInCsp = false` means "when this key object gets freed, delete the backing key material".  So when garbage collection cleans up after this method it does what you told it to: delete the private key.

Since for a smart card the certificate is stored within the private key container as associated metadata, this deletes the certificate as well.

If you remove that line of code your key/cert deletion problems should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that I only need to add on the CryptoConfig ones. So, I took the line below from the loop and put it on form show it solved my problem.

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), signatureRSAMethod);
```